# How do i pass two values to the partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, partial, formtastic

I have this chunk of code

```
 <%= semantic_form_for @tournament do |f| %>
    <%= f.semantic_fields_for :courts do |builder| %>
        <%= render :partial => "court_fields", :locals => { :f => builder } %>
        <span class="links">
         <%= link_to_add_fields "Add More Court", f, :courts %>
        </span>
    <% end %>
```

here is the partial

```
<div class="nested_fields">
<%= f.input :name %>
<%= f.input :address %>
<%= f.input :city %>
<%= f.input :state %>
<%= f.input :zip %>
<%= f.input :phone %>
<%= f.input :contact_name %>
<%= link_to_remove_fields "Remove Court", f %>
</div>
```

but what i really need is have the span in the partial also so its enclosed in the nested_fields div... I tried

```
<%= semantic_form_for @tournament do |f| %>
    <%= f.semantic_fields_for :courts do |builder| %>
  <%= render :partial => "court_fields", :locals => { :f => builder, :original_f => f } %>
<% end %>
```

and in the partial

```
<div class="nested_fields">
<%= f.input :name %>
<%= f.input :address %>
<%= f.input :city %>
<%= f.input :state %>
<%= f.input :zip %>
<%= f.input :phone %>
<%= f.input :contact_name %>
<%= link_to_remove_fields "Remove Court", f %>
<span class="links">
 <%= link_to_add_fields "Add More Court", original_f, :courts %>
</span>
</div>
```

but i got this error below...what am I doing wrong and maybe my whole understanding of partial is off, any help would be appreciated...

```
undefined local variable or method `original_f' for #<#<Class:0x000001035d5a80>:0x000001035cd920>
```

My helpers

```
def link_to_remove_fields(name, f)
  f.hidden_field(:_destroy) + link_to_function(name, "remove_fields(this)")
end

def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association)
  new_object = f.object.class.reflect_on_association(association).klass.new
  fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, :child_index => "new_#{association}") do |builder|
    render(association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", :f => builder)
  end
  link_to_function(name, ("add_fields(this, \"#{association}\", \"#{escape_javascript(fields)}\")"))
end
```

Comment: Can you post your `link_to_add_fields` helper?

Comment: Your understanding (and mine) of partials seems correct - [related q](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186504/multivariable-partial-in-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: Your usage of partials is correct. If original_f were undefined in partial, link_to_add_fields "Add More Court", original_f, :courts would raise an error on the view. Your error is somewhere inside the helper. Maybe inside the render call. Does the partial :court_fields use the original_f variable??

Answer (score 0):

```
render(association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", :f => builder)
```

No `original_f` in that partial rendering?

Comment: I mean: court_fields use f and original_f. In the first render you send both, ok, but in this render inside the helper you send only f. Am I missing something?